# Github losing revisions?

Tags: git, github

I work for a small web dev company and we are using private repository in github to keep our code. The way our workflow is organized is that each dev would work on a local repository and do frequent commits, but only push changes to github when the code is working. When a feature/change/fix is ready for production we use git pull on production servers to pull changes off of github. Just a few minutes ago we found that github is 56 revisions old, compared to production servers. At first, we thought that one of us has merged his work directly on production instead of doing a merge locally and pushing the result to github, but logs and command history on production boxes seem to indicate that only pull command was used. What could happen to cause github to completely lose 56 revisions?

Comment: Why don't you contact GitHub's support on this matter? Especially if you have a private repository which means that you pay money every month.

Comment: don't rely that a free service should be 100% perfect, better use your own repository (i recommend you Mercurial) we also had bad experience with both google code (i call it now loose code) and github and i completely deny their reliability, cant trust them for work.

Comment: @venimus GitHub isn't free if he has a private repository.

Answer (score 10):

Does anyone on your team use `git push -f` as part of their workflow?

My best guess is that someone is force-pushing and didn't pull in someone's commits. It's *extremely* difficult to lose data using Git without force pushing, but if you're force pushing without knowing the consequences, it's easy to think someone is "losing" data when it's actually yourself deleting it.